# Is a handful of rice the amount of rice that fills up one or two palms?

Tags: meaning, ambiguity

If we say “we only have a handful of rice, then technically do we only have the amount of rice that fills up just one palm alone, or is it the amount that fillms the palms of **both** hands?

Is there anyone saying “technically we only have two handfuls of rice”?

Comment: As interesting as the question is, it can still be answered using a dictionary, as it stands here, and is therefore off-topic. Please see the help section.

Comment: Imagine a hand cupped so as to resemble a large spoon or scoop.

Comment: It's not technical. There's no standard of measure established by any measurement standardizing government institution by any government, recognized or otherwise. But non-technically, it means mostly just one hand. No one is saying "technically we have 2 handfuls of rice". Don't get so hung up on technicalities. Wait, is someone trying to cheat you out of rice?

Comment: The more approximate sense given by [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handful) **2.
a small amount, number, or quantity** is the only one I'd regard as sensible to consider here. Even I would measure using standard cups or spoons.

Comment: I've always understood it to mean one hand.  But, as others indicate, the measure is incredibly imprecise.  (Just image the variation in the size of human hands.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionaries (from the *OED* to online references) define "handful" as the quantity that fills up *the* hand, so the amount you can grasp in one hand.  For two hands' worth, we have "double handful." From [*August is a Good Time for Killing*](https://books.google.com/books?id=REOU3rv9lWkC&pg=PT54&dq=%22double%20handful%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwBDgKahUKEwjd4_TCsdjGAhUVE5IKHXqwA8Y#v=onepage&q=%22double%20handful%22&f=false) by Martin Greenberg:

> Tom scooped up a **double handful** of silver money. "Take it, sir,"
>   he said.  "and you may have as much more as you want of it."  He poured
>   into the dish that the good man made of his **hands**,...

For more than a double handful, use the plural "handfuls."

Answer (score 0):

[Handful](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/handful)

> noun, plural handfuls.
>
> 1.the quantity or amount that the hand can hold:
> a handful of coins.

A handful refers to the amount that can be held in **one** hand, not both.

Comment: so "2 handfuls of rice" is ok?

Comment: If that's what you want to say, yes. The amount of rice held in both of your hands would be equivalent to two handfuls of rice.

Comment: Please include citations for direct quotations.

Comment: The link is in the word "Handful."